# How to count cells that cointain a "string"

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet containing 2800+ rows of server names. When we decommission a server the server name is appended with ".decom". I need a count of how many in the column contain the ".decom". In sql I would have used a simple "like '%decom%', but I am not sure how to do this in excel or if it is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNTIF()` with a wildcard string.  Just do this:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A100,"*.decom")
```

(Assumes your range is `A1:A100`, so modify as needed.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [v-lookup](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) and specify a wild card?

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&C1&"*",author_names!A1:B100,1,FALSE)
```

If you need to check if a string is contained in another string you can use `SEARCH` or `FIND`.

Answer (score 0):

JonH -- wild cards are not permitted in `vlookup()`, however they can be used with `index(match())`

eg: `index( author_names!a1:a100,match("*"&c1&"*",author_names!a1:a100,0))`

note the return value is the value of the first matching wild card found.

BTW: your `vlookup()` example specifies 2 columns (A &B) but you're returning only the first column value (1), so my example does the same... if you really meant to return the value of the second column in the `vlookup()`, change my example to `'author_names!b1:b100', immediately following 'index('.`